# AWGN generator for .NET

Tags: .net, matlab, signal-processing, octave, noise

I'm looking for an Additive White Gaussian Noise generator for .NET.

1. I know that somewhere there is some degree of interoperability between .NET and MATLAB, which has a AWGN generator, but I don't know if its free **EDIT** and [I just found it](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/).
2. Probably other applications as GNU Octave, which have similar functionalities to MATLAB, have .NET bindings. I didn't an extensive search on this matter.
3. I would rather use a .NET library that has this function. From the ones I know:
4. [Math.NET Neodym](http://neodym.mathdotnet.com) doesn't seem to have it.
5. [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/checkout) has a Gaussian number generator, but I lack the understanding of AWGN to know if this generator could be used for this purpose. Any ideas?

Comment: To what will you be applying this generator? AWGN is "background" noise added on to some kind of signal; what signal will you be using in your code?

Comment: @Stobor, let's say I just need a White Gaussian signal generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGWN is just a Gaussian (normally) distributed number added to each value of a numeric array.  So all you need is a Gaussian random numerber generator (RNG).

There is one in chapter 7 of [Practical Numerical Methods in C# by Jack Xu](http://www.drxudotnet.com/numerical_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know you already found it, but I figured I'd post the link here to help complete the Q&A paradigm.

MATLAB can deploy .NET or COM components using [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/) and [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler).  It's a bit pricey, but can often save a lot of time when you can prototype and develop your numerical algorithms in MATLAB and avoid recoding in a faster language.